# Possible ways to send "StringValue" from One View Controller to multiple ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uinavigationcontroller

i am trying to create one reusable datePicker. in my project i am using multiple Labels in multiple viewControllers. For that i created one DatePicker class that one i am using different places. check this below code its working for Single viewController.
This is the one VC i am displaying date here which i have selected date from CustomDatePickerViewController.

```
import UIKit

class SelectDateViewController: UIViewController {
    var dateString_fromCustomVC = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("dateString_fromCustomVC",dateString_fromCustomVC)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func selectDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomDatePickerViewController") as! CustomDatePickerViewController


        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.view.frame = view.bounds
        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

} i am displaying date

    import UIKit

    class SelectDateViewController: UIViewController {
        var dateString_fromCustomVC = String()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print("dateString_fromCustomVC",dateString_fromCustomVC)

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        @IBAction func selectDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

            let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomDatePickerViewController") as! CustomDatePickerViewController


            self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
            self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
            popOverVC.view.frame = view.bounds
            popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        }

    }
```

This is my CustomDatePickerViewController class.

```
import UIKit

class CustomDatePickerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.frame.size.height =  UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
    }

    @IBAction func saveDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

        myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: myDatePicker.date)
        print("selectedDate",selectedDate)

         let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectDateViewController") as! SelectDateViewController
        popOverVC.dateString_fromCustomVC = selectedDate


        self.removeAnimate()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

    }
    func showAnimate()
    {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.10, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        });
    }

    func removeAnimate()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished)
            {
                self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        });
    }

}
```

i can able to send selected  date from  CustomDatePickerViewController  to SelectDateViewController, But how to send selected date to different view controllers.

Comment: Use notification Center

Comment: Why you don't want to use a delegation pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i resolved my problem by taking @ Bence Pattogato suggestions. see my following updated code.

i created one protocol class . file name is CustomDatePickerDelegate.swift

```
protocol CustomDatePickerDelegate {
        func CustomDateSeletced(value: String)
}
```

now this is my updated code in CustomDatePickerViewController class.

```
import UIKit

class CustomDatePickerViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    var delegate: CustomDatePickerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.frame.size.height =  UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
    }


    @IBAction func saveDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

        myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        let saveDate = dateFormatter.string(from: myDatePicker.date)
        print("selectedDate",saveDate)
        delegate?.CustomDateSeletced(value: saveDate) **//This is the way i am saving date value  from date picker**
        self.removeAnimate()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

    }
    func showAnimate()
    {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.10, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        });
    }

    func removeAnimate()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished)
            {
                self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        });
    }

}
```

now i am using this delegate in SelectDateViewController. see my following updated code.

```
  import UIKit

class SelectDateViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var selectedDateLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBAction func selectDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomDatePickerViewController") as! CustomDatePickerViewController
        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.view.frame = view.bounds
        popOverVC.delegate = self
        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }
}
extension SelectDateViewController:CustomDatePickerDelegate
{
    func CustomDateSeletced(value: String) {
        selectedDateLabel.text = value
    }    
}
```

code clean purpose i am using extension over there.

Comment: Make the var delegate —> weak var delegate, otherways they hold strong reference to each other and they never will be released from the memory.

Comment: Coding: to be swifty always write function names with camel case (lowercased first letter, then every new word’s first letter uppercased).

Comment: thank you for suggestions coming to coding i am working on demo project i am not concentrated much on case.

Answer (score 3):

To send notifications can be a solution, but I think from an architectural point of view, this is a lot better (easier to maintain, extend, etc.).
Use a observer (multiple delegates) pattern for example. Create a protocol like this. After implementing, consider [this](https://marcosantadev.com/swift-arrays-holding-elements-weak-references/) for resolving retain cycles for the array.

```
protocol DatePickerProtocol {
    func dateStringChanged(to newString: String)
}

class CustomDatePickerViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    var delegates: [DatePickerProtocol]?

    @IBAction func saveDateAction(_ sender: Any) {
        .....
        if let delegates {
            for delegate in delegates {
                delegate.dateStringChanged(to: "selectedDate string")
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}

class SelectDateViewController: UIViewController, DatePickerProtocol {
    ...
    // get a reference to CustomDatePickerViewController and register this class like:
    dataPickerViewController.delegates.append(self)

    func dateStringChanged(to newString: String) {
        // Do whatever with the new date string
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Bence Pattogato i accepted ur suggestions and i implemented protocol.  please review my code give me your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a **Notification** with **NotificationCenter** and you can add observer in the viewController and update the labels.

When you want to send the date you can post a notification like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "SelectedDate", object: nil, userInfo: ["selectedDate": Date that you selected])
```

After that, you can add observer in the other viewController where you want to receive that notification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(datePicked(notification:)), name: "SelectedDate", object: nil)


@objc func datePicked(notification: Notification) {
      //get the date here
      print(notification.userInfo?["selectedDate"])
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a `DataSource` and read them in the views you need them:

```
class DateDataSource {
    var date : Date?
    static let sharedInstance = DateDataSource()
    private init() {}
}
```

When you get your date from the picker you'll set it like:

`DateDataSouce.sharedInstance.date = theDate`

Then in the views where you need to display it you'll call

`let theDate = DateDataSouce.sharedInstance.date`

Comment: Why bother inheriting from `NSObject`? It's not necessary at all.

Comment: I wouldn't use a singleton to achieve this functionality, rather make use of notifications.

Comment: 1. I would not use an app-life-long living static instance for this purpose. 2. With this, the viewcontrollers don't get updates on changes, just can fetch the data.